# hwclock vs rcS.d/S11hwclock.sh what is the difference between the two?

Tags: filesystem

Could someone kindly explain the difference between these two files?

hwclock.sh

rcS.d/S11hwclock.sh

I understand these files are both to do with the motherboard clock, but i dont see the difference.....

Answer (score 0):

> hwclock is a tool for accessing the Hardware Clock. You can display
>   the current time, set the Hardware Clock to a specified time, set the
>   Hardware Clock to the System Time, and set the System Time from the
>   Hardware Clock.

<sup>Source: [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hwclock)</sup>

S11hwclock.sh is where hwclock gets called.

Comment: Is there a timing system on linux which shows how many time units since the installation, regardless of the current system time (in case the time was changed)?

Comment: Honestly do not know.